# Tricky z-index issue with mobile menu and animated content

Tags: css, z-index

On my site I have a `z-index` issue where the content's `z-index` is lower though appears *above* the menus (`z-index: 4;`) on mobile/resized browsers (horizontally resize until the images horizontally align with the mobile menu). Here is the reasoning behind the related CSS:

- The CSS animation can not happen without CSS generated `content` so I had to add a `div` element as a parent to the images.
- The `div` used for the animation interferes with the Image Viewer and JavaScript detects the click or tap `event.target` as the `div` instead of the image.
- Adding `position: relative; z-index: 1;` resolves *that issue* and allows the images to be clicked/tapped and viewed in the Image Viewer though creates the issue for *this post*.
- On mobile these images incorrectly appear closer to the user than the menus in spite of the fact that the `ul` for the menu has a `z-index: 4;` *and* uses `position: fixed;`.

What I've tried thus far:

- I've tried changing the various `position` values while maintaining the current layout without any luck.
- Using `z-index: 4 !important;` has no effect on the menu.
- Setting `z-index: 0;` or invalid/lower values for the images in the content results in the `event.target` for clicking/tapping to revert back to the `div` parent element (needed for the animation).
- Ensured that other elements *and* the CSS generated elements do not have conflicting property/value pairs such as `position` and `z-index`.

The issue occurs in Waterfox, Chrome and Safari. I'm pretty baffled considering that `relative` is given less emphasis than `fixed` *plus* that higher `z-index` values are not being honored...by all the browsers ... at the same time. I'm still tackling the problem though at this point I could really use a second opinion.

This is a temporary URL not intended for search engines to index:
https://www.johnbilicki.com/eridel/

Thoughts please?

Comment: Which animation are you referring to? Your description is pretty concise but I'm not entirely clear on what exactly it's in context of. Also if you're afraid of the SE's and your link add `rel="nofollow"` to it.

Comment: @ChrisW. The border animation where the borders animate in `width` clock-wise and then the ending/fading "pow". Is there a `rel="nofollow"` on Stack? If so I'm not aware and I'd be happy to edit the post as need be. (Edit: ah, it's `nofollow` by default, that works!)

Comment: Oh right, ya I completely forgot about the markdown but ya of course these smart folks thought of it already lol :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so for starters especially if you're going to sell it as a service, I'd strongly suggest learning more about natural [semantic structure](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html) and [DOM Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow) since you have your element structure pretty obfuscated. A quick example would be your ordering of `main` above `header` elements and the tricks you're using to situate things visually that wouldn't be necessary if you had a natural DOM flow (which also would cut your CSS/html into a fraction of what it is and increase performance when the site is being "painted" / rendered and you wouldn't need to explicitly define z-index's or run into as many cross-browser issues and such, like your CMS thingy appears way cleaner?

However, a quick fix to your current dilemma. Just go remove `z-index: 0` from your CSS selector `body > header` and voila, you're back on track. Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: BAM! That worked! Thank you! As to the other suggestions the DOM structure is intended to display the content *first* in the absence of CSS. Additionally Google's recommendation to serve a page/headers/etc in the same format as a physical newspaper is something I agree with independent of other considerations. I test with all sorts of miscellaneous and wonky browsers that I can. Additionally the code is fair minified: it's all loaded to reduce the number of HTTP requests. There is a *lot* of intent behind every bit of code. Now if I can just get the menu `:checked` issue in Firefox resolved...

Comment: @John What's the menu `:checked` issue? There's usually a workaround for anything these days.

Comment: Please forgive me, I'm *really* tired trying to fix my circadian rhythm... I blindly uploaded all the theme files and it was resolved. The mobile menu uses a hidden checkbox so even if JavaScript is disabled it will still work. It was working locally though not live. I had to fix the `z-index` a little bit more to work with the modals on the main website (this is the portfolio site) and it's all working now. I appreciate your help, it's no easy task tracking as much detail as I have to. ︎